# How to switch the (single/double) quotes for a Tweet me button

Tags: quotes

I spent about 2 hours trying to make a blending of 2 codes work, and feeling the weakness of my code skills, I am reaching out here for some help.

I think the problem lies in the single/double quotes. I tried many, many times to reformat the quotations (and both ways ie reformatting both scripts to accommodate each other).

The image (which should be linked) is added to the page in the functions.php -- the image is path/image.png in this example:

```
! is_admin() && add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content )
{
    if( in_the_loop() )   // <-- Target the main loop
    {
        $prepend = "<div style='color:#808080  ; border:1px solid #909090 ; border-radius:5px; float:left; padding-top:1px;'>&nbsp;<**img src='/path/image.png' alt='Tweet this' style='margin-bottom: -4px; '**>Tweet this &#8202;</div>&nbsp;";
        $content = $prepend . $content;
    } 
    return $content;
}, 9 );
```

This is the link -- When the user clicks the image, I want them to access this link:

```
<a href='https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php echo $post_url ?>&text=<?php echo $post_title ?>' onclick='window.open(this.href,"popupwindow", "width=800,height=500,left=200,top=5,scrollbars,toolbar=0,resizable"); return false;' Target='_blank' >twitter</a>
```

What I want to end up with is: Click the image on the page, (it opens the Twitter link,) user gets to Tweet (share) the post they are on on Twitter.

So user clicks image (path/image.png) and opens link (twitter.com...etc).

Comment: Do you mean the `href` value of your 2nd code part should take place in the `$prepend` value of the 1st part, sustituting to the (currently) `/path/image.png`? But what about the `<?php echo ... ?>` in this 2nd part? Are they replaced before incorporating the link? Please give a clear complete architecture of what you plan.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. I just want to take the path/image.png and link that image to the link in the second piece of code. I want to end up with just the first piece of code, but add the link from the second piece of code to that image. I'm not sure I'm describing this adequately.

Comment: Sorry but I continue to be unsure. Please edit your question with a clear "Here is what I want to end up with" example, where you highlight the part which comes from elsewhere. Something like `the-expected-resulting-string-**this comes from...**-the-end-of-resulting-string`.

Comment: Thank you. I have made it more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure of anything: you should realize that your question lacks clarity.
Notably because you don't say where `$post_url` and `$post_title` comes from, nor explain what are `$prepend` and `$content`, and don't explain at all your function's use and context.

But I'll talk about what I believe to have understood.

Your goal seems to result in this kind of HTML part:

```
<div style="color:#808080; border:1px solid #909090; border-radius:5px; float:left; padding-top:1px;">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=the-post_url&text=the-post_title"
    onclick="window.open(this.href,'popupwindow','width=800,height=500,left=200,top=5,scrollbars,toolbar=0,resizable'); return false;"
    target="_blank">
        <img src="/path/image.png" alt="Tweet this" style="margin-bottom:-4px;">
        Tweet this &#8202;
    </a>
</div>
```

(you'll notice that I've returned back to arbitrary give precedence to double-quotes, which is the most standard choice)

Say we call `$div`, `$a`, and `$img` the source main components, to output the desired block we simply have to write something like:
`echo $div . $a . $img . 'Tweet this &#8202;</a></div';`

I suppose the issue you're reporting comes from you have to define those components as strings, while they already include simple and double quotes.

So the answer is using the PHP [*heredoc* syntax](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

> Heredoc text behaves just like a double-quoted string, without the double quotes. This means that quotes in a heredoc do not need to be escaped, but the escape codes listed above can still be used. Variables are expanded, but the same care must be taken when expressing complex variables inside a heredoc as with strings.

And the components definition should look like:

```
$div = <<<EOT
<div style="color:#808080; border:1px solid #909090; border-radius:5px; float:left; padding-top:1px;">
EOT;
$a = <<<EOT
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=$post_url&text=$post_title"  onclick="window.open(this.href,'popupwindow','width=800,height=500,left=200,top=5,scrollbars,toolbar=0,resizable'); return false;" target="_blank">
EOT;
$img = <<<EOT
<img src="/path/image.png" alt="Tweet this" style="margin-bottom:-4px;">
EOT;
```

In fact many other variations may be considered, notably directly using a unique variable for the whole part...

---

**EDIT:**

Here is a working whole snippet, after integrating a value for `$post_url`and `$post_title` and corrected a typo in `echo...`:

```
$post_url="the-post-url";
$post_title="the-post-title";
$div = <<<EOT
<div style="color:#808080; border:1px solid #909090; border-radius:5px; float:left; padding-top:1px;">
EOT;
$a = <<<EOT
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=$post_url&text=$post_title"  onclick="window.open(this.href,'popupwindow','width=800,height=500,left=200,top=5,scrollbars,toolbar=0,resizable'); return false;" target="_blank">
EOT;
$img = <<<EOT
<img src="/path/image.png" alt="Tweet this" style="margin-bottom:-4px;" />
EOT;
echo $div . $a . $img . 'Tweet this &#8202;</a></div>';
```

Comment: Sorry. I see now where I wasn't being clear. In this case, I didn't think the use of the functions was important. $PostURL and $PostTitle are part of the script that comes from Twitter--that whole line is just copied and pasted from https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button Tweet Button.) I simply wanted to wrap the image (or div) with a simple <a href>, the way it'd done in the most basic html. But I can't, because I can't get the single and double quotations to work together. I tried the two solutions offered, but couldn't get those to work, unfortunately. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "I tried the two solutions offered, but couldn't get those to work". I edited my answer with the complete snippet based on the unique solution I suggested, then I just tested it and it works as expected.

Comment: Thank you, sir. That last piece of code worked just great. People, please upvote cFreed here. His commitment to helping out some novice coder here is really something!